# Sending weight data from a scale through wireless RS232 device to web server

Tags: serial-port, webserver, scale

I have been programming this little WiFly RS232 device PuTTY. It is a small grey device that pretty much just sends data from an RS232 port wirelessly to our web server. There is a giant advanced user manual I have scanned through many many times now looking for someway to fix this and you can find it here: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002230A.pdf

This device is already hooked up to the web and the web server and I have posted data from other devices with it before. The issue I am having with it now is that the data that I am getting from the scale is in a really weird format. Originally it would send very weird looking character, then using "set opt format 0x7" I was able to get it to send the data in hex.

I can't seem to figure out how to translate that data to decimal so we can view the weight values correctly on the website. There must be a command for this that I am just missing or maybe it is more difficult than I realize.

Comment: The link you provided for the Microchip WiFly device is not sufficient.  That's a manual for the device that is involved in the *transfer* of the data, and only one half of the data link.  Apparently your root problem(s) is/are that you have no idea of how that data from the scale is formatted and/or both ends of the data link are not properly configured.  **So what is the manufacturer and model of this scale? Where's the manual for it?**  BTW calling the format *"weird"* is not helpful nor informative, as that is a purely subjective term.

Comment: First off I can only post one link so sorry. Second, here's the manual for the scale http://www.globalindustrial.com/site/images/universal/product_extras/300625_Digital_Shipping&Receiving_Scale.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I work in the weighing industry and spend a lot of time talking to various scales via RS232.

Most scales on the market send the weight data in Ascii format with a [cr][lf] terminator, e.g. "`NET     2.045 kg[cr][lf]`". If you are getting strange characters back, it is usually down to a mismatch in baud rate etc between the scale and the client. The scale manufacturer will usually have a communication manual which will detail the com protocol and give you an idea of what you should be receiving.

Have you tried communicating with the scale via HyperTerminal or YAT etc?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, thank you someone who knows what they are talking about. I appreciate you getting back to me. I was thinking it might be a mismatched baud rate. I can get the scale to talk straight to the serial terminal if I use 2400 baud when plugged straight into my PC. That will produce the weight from the scale in the right format. Where as I think the wifly device I am using usually runs at 9600 baud. So when I try to run the scale to the Wifly device I feel like I am not getting the baud rate right somewhere. The only user manual I have been able to find for the scale is this one

Comment: http://www.globalindustrial.com/site/images/universal/product_extras/300625_Digital_Shipping&Receiving_Scale.pdf. I haven't tried those yet I will do that. This was very helpful at least to start getting on the right path. Thank you.

Comment: If you can think of anything else that would help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like the scale has fixed com settings. The interface device that you are using must be configured to have exactly the same com settings for the data to be able to get through successfully. Also, make sure that Hardware Handshaking that is enabled. _"RS-232 Serial Port Communication
This scale is designed to send the data through
the RS-232 serial port continuously.
Communication properties:
Code used: ASCII
Bits per second: 2400 bps
Data bits: 8 BITS
Parity: None
Stop bits: 1 bit
Flow control: Hardware"_

Comment: Section 2 of the WiFly Manual details how to change the COM settings

Comment: This is what I got from my "get everything" command on the wifly RS232 device.

Comment: Rec:(12:22:08)get everything
wifly-EZX Ver 4.00.1, Apr 19 2013 11:47:20 on RN-171
Beacon=102
Reboot=0
IF=UP
DHCP=ON
IP=192.168.43.40:2000
NM=255.255.255.0
GW=192.168.43.1
HOST=0.0.0.0:80
PROTO=TCP,HTTP,
MTU=1524
FLAGS=0x7
TCPMODE=0x0
BACKUP=0.0.0.0
OPEN=*OPEN*
CLOSE=*CLOS*
REMOTE=GET /update?key=XBJ66EPANED3G8K4&weight=
FlushSize=1420
MatchChar=0
FlushTimer=5
IdleTimer=0
CmdChar=$
DNS=192.168.43.1
Name=api.rfinspired.com
Backup=rn.microchip.com
Lea=es86400
FTP=0.0.0.0:21
File=wifly-EZX.img
User=roving
Pass=Pass123
Dir=public
Timeout=200
FTP_mode=0x0
SSID=danarys
Chan=0
ExtAnt=0

Comment: Linkmon-Infra=30
Linkmon-AP=3600
Passphrase=82478247
TxPower=12
EAP_Id=userid
EAP_User=peap-user
SleepTmr=0
WakeTmr=0
Trigger=0x1
Autoconn=0
IoFunc=0x0
IoMask=0x21f0
Join=1
Auth=OPEN
Mask=0x1fff
Rate=12, 24 M
IoValu=0x0
DebugReg=0x0
PrintLvl=0x1
LaunchStr=web_app
TimeEna=0
TIMEADR=64.90.182.55:123
Zone=7
Baudrate=2400
Flow=0x0
Mode=0x2
Cmd_GPIO=0
JoinTmr=1000
Replace=0x24
DeviceId=WiFly-EZX
Password=
Format=0x0
Signal=0
Average=5
BCAST=255.255.255.255:55555
Interval=0x7
Backup=0.0.0.0:0
Sensor=0x0
SensePwr=0x0

Comment: My apologies I didn't realize this would look like such a mess here. Well if you have the time. I just don't know what I am missing. I swear I have set it up as it is suppose to be, however I am still getting no data to pop up on the web server. All I get is question marks, no weird characters anymore just question marks sometimes one and sometimes a couple.

Comment: Have you enabled Hardware Flow Control?? Your output specifies Flow=0x0 - according to the manual "Flow control is not enabled by default; you set it with the set uart flow 1 command" If you are getting no data at all, it is likely because the scale is not seeing the Rts/Cts lines changing.

Comment: I would highly recommend connecting the Scale to your PC first and testing the comms with something like YAT (http://sourceforge.net/projects/y-a-terminal/), this way you can be sure that it is the WiFly not the Scale that is causing the issues. You can also determine what data you should be expecting to see on your web server.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out today.